# Google plus button appears blank

Tags: button, google-plus

I have implemented a Google plus button on my [website](http://nativor.co.il/page/%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%A5.aspx), when I hover over the button I get a blank square with no description of the website see screenshot:
[image: blank google plus]

If I press the button I get an error. this seems to be happening on all the google plus buttons versions I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hover isn't blank, the text that is supposed to appear in that hover is just appearing to the left of where it is supposed to. I believe that is due to not setting the language code. Where you load your script add a line to specify the language:

```
<!--Share buttons scripts-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">
window.___gcfg = {lang: 'iw'};  //ADD ME

(function() {
var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();</script><!--Share buttons scripts end-->
```

That should resolve the incorrect rendering of the hover.

Now for the error when you click the button. When the button is clicked, the service goes and tries to render a preview of the target page. You don't have an data-href value listed on the button markup so the service then relies on the canonical link, which in your case is the cause of the problem. You're canonical link is http://www.navitor.co.il/ which does not load and also is probably not the URL that you intended to share.

Correct the canonical link so that sharing works and so that Google search doesn't get confused about a pointer to a broken URL.

References:

- [Setting the +1 button target URL](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#target-url)
- [Canonicalization](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139066)

Comment: Thank you, your solution solved me the issue with the page not found issue, but I am still having problems with the empty square near the Google plus profile when I am hovering on the button